# Recursive method stopping prematurely on certain branches

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following recursive method to create a mountain in a height mapping:

```
private void createMountain(final float[][] heightMapping, final float startHeight) {
    boolean[][] traversed = new boolean[width][depth];
    boolean positive = (startHeight >= 0f);
    int x = random.nextInt(width);
    int z = random.nextInt(depth);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x, z, startHeight, positive);
}

private void recursiveUpdate(final float[][] heightMapping, final boolean[][] traversed, final int x, final int z, final float startHeight, final boolean positive) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width || z < 0 || z >= depth) {
        return;
    }
    if (traversed[x][z]) {
        return;
    }
    if ((positive && startHeight <= 0f) || (!positive && startHeight >= 0f)) {
        heightMapping[x][z] = 0f;
        return;
    }
    traversed[x][z] = true;
    heightMapping[x][z] = startHeight;
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x - 1, z - 1, calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x - 1, z + 1, calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x + 1, z - 1, calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x + 1, z + 1, calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
}

private float calculateNewStartHeight(final float startHeight, final boolean positive) {
    float delta = random.nextFloat() * maxHeight / maxDecayFactor;
    return (positive) ? startHeight - delta : startHeight + delta;
}
```

The idea is that it starts at `(x, z)` and then recursively lowers the values of the surrounding cells (left-bottom/right-bottom/left-top/right-top), howevers it seems to skip cells, as seen by the following output:

```
0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.5  0.0  0.9  0.0  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  1.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
1.8  0.0  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  2.4  0.0  0.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
3.6  0.0  0.8  0.0  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  4.4  0.0  1.2  0.0  0.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
3.5  0.0  2.3  0.0  0.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  2.5  0.0  1.1  0.0  0.6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
1.4  0.0  0.4  0.0  0.4  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

On the left, slightly above the middle you can see `4.4`, and the issue itself seems pretty obvious, it does not set any values for the top/down/left/right elements, however I thought my recursion had caught that issue.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @KubaSpatny Yes, and there is no 'bug' in the code, it is some design flaw in my algorithm which I fail to grasp.

Comment: What should the output be? Your explanation above your output looks like it is outputting what it should be.

Comment: @mdewitt I'm using this heightmap to project terrain in a 3D program. Right now, there are holes in the mountain (take `0.0  4.4  0.0  1.2`, it has holes at both `0.0` whereas I'd expect first some value lower than `4.4` and secondly some value in between `4.4` and `1.2`.

Comment: Right but you said you wanted to only do the surround left bottom, right-bottom, left-top, right-top. So you actually want ALL surrounding, including left, left bottom, left top, top, right top, right, and right bottom?

Comment: I once spent 3 weeks trying to figure out my code,it turned out to be from the parentheses in my if condition. So do that: 
if ((x < 0 || x >= width) || (z < 0 || z >= depth))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calculating the recursive height for the top, bottom, left and right. You are only calculating the corners. You just need to add the "non-corner", ie. the top, bottom, left and right indicies of (x, y) to your recursive method.

```
private void recursiveUpdate(final float[][] heightMapping, final boolean[][] traversed,
    final int x, final int z, final float startHeight, final boolean positive) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width || z < 0 || z >= depth) {
        return;
    }
    if (traversed[x][z]) {
        return;
    }
    if ((positive && startHeight <= 0f) || (!positive && startHeight >= 0f)) {
        heightMapping[x][z] = 0f;
        return;
    }

    traversed[x][z] = true;
    heightMapping[x][z] = startHeight;
    //This will only calculate the corners of the (x,y point)
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x - 1, z - 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x - 1, z + 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x + 1, z - 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x + 1, z + 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);

    //Add top, bottom, left and right indicies for (x,y)
    //bottom
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x, z - 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    //top
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x, z + 1, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    //right
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x + 1, z, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
    //left
    recursiveUpdate(heightMapping, traversed, x - 1, z, 
                    calculateNewStartHeight(startHeight, positive), positive);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed fixed it. Even managed to 'optimize' it a little by recursing on the top/down/left/right, which was initially my idea actually.